# how to plot RMSE vs number of trees tries in bagging when using train() and cross validation in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, tree, regression

I am studying this website about bagging method. https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/bagging.html

I am going to use train() function with cross validation for bagging. something like below. 
as far as I realized nbagg=200 tells r to try 200 trees, calculate RMSE for each and return the number of trees ( here 80 ) for which the best RMSE is achieved. 
now how can I see what RMSE other nbagg values have produced in this model. like RMSE vs number of trees plot in that website ( begore introdicing cv method and train() function like plot below)

```
ames_bag2 <- train(
  Sale_Price ~ .,
  data = ames_train,
  method = "treebag",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
  nbagg = 200,  
  control = rpart.control(minsplit = 2, cp = 0)
)
ames_bag2
## Bagged CART 
## 
## 2054 samples
##   80 predictor
## 
## No pre-processing
## Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
## Summary of sample sizes: 1849, 1848, 1848, 1849, 1849, 1847, ... 
## Resampling results:
## 
##   RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
##   26957.06  0.8900689  16713.14
```

[image]

Comment: did my answer solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As the example you shared is not completely reproducible, I have taken a different example from the `mtcars` dataset to illustrate how you can do it. You can extend that for your data.

Note: The RMSE showed here is the average of 10 RMSEs as the CV number is 10 here. So we will store that only. Adding the relevant libraries too in the example here. And setting the maximum number of trees as 15, just for the example.

```
library(ipred)
library(caret)
library(rpart)
library(dplyr)
data("mtcars")

n_trees <-1

error_df <- data.frame()

while (n_trees <= 15) {
  
  ames_bag2 <- train(
    mpg ~.,
    data = mtcars,
    method = "treebag",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
    nbagg = n_trees,  
    control = rpart.control(minsplit = 2, cp = 0)
  )
  
  error_df %>%
    bind_rows(data.frame(trees=n_trees, rmse=mean(ames_bag2[["resample"]]$RMSE)))-> error_df
    
  n_trees <- n_trees+1
  
}
```

`error_df` will show the output.

```
> error_df
   trees     rmse
1      1 2.493117
2      2 3.052958
3      3 2.052801
4      4 2.239841
5      5 2.500279
6      6 2.700347
7      7 2.642525
8      8 2.497162
9      9 2.263527
10    10 2.379366
11    11 2.447560
12    12 2.314433
13    13 2.423648
14    14 2.192112
15    15 2.256778
```